# How to remove an orphan code-behind module of a form created due to a bug in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

This took me a while to figure out the solution and I couldn't find anything on the web about it, so I share it here. Here is the problem (bug):

In MS Access (2013 and presumably previous versions) when you create a new form, and add some VBA code behind it before saving the form and giving it a name, sometimes when things get messy, the name of the code-behind module does not update to reflect the new name, causing a disconnected form and VBA code.

For example you create a new form that will temporarily be named `Form1`. You set its `Has Module` property to `Yes` which creates a `Form_Form1` module in `Microsoft Access Class Objects`. Then you mess with other things before remembering to save the form, giving it the name `MyForm` and some time later you  face this error:

> The form name 'Form1' is misspelled or refers to a form that doesn't exist.

The `Form_Form1` module has not been renamed and remains there even if you delete `MyForm`.

I tried creating a new form, saving it as `Form1` and then setting its `Has Module` property to `Yes` but unfortunately this last step gives gives an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Take a backup of your database file just in case something goes wrong. Then open it.
- Create a new form without saving. Let's say it is named `Form2`
  before saving.
- Set the unsaved form's `Has Module` property to `Yes`. Then save the
  form and name it the same name as your old (deleted) form.
- Now set the saved form's `Has Module` property to `No` and confirm
  removal of the (orphan) code behind, and save again.
- We now have another temporary orphan code-behind module for `Form2`,
  but surprisingly this time we can easily remove it:
- Create another new form and save it with name `Form2`. Set its `Has
  Module` property to `Yes` (This time it works despite the new orphan
  module being there!) and save again and close.
- Now delete `Form2` which will also remove the temporary module and
  everything should be fine now.

Let me know if it works for you also :)